# How to convert gp4 file to pdf

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, converters

There is any opensource convertor available or java api for converting gp4 file to pdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guitar Pro? [Here is one GPL licensed Java project (DGuitar)](http://dguitar.sourceforge.net/en/index.html) that implements the gp4 file format.